# doctrine cant find my BaseModels in the models/generated folder

Tags: doctrine

when i use a Doctrine Model Doctrine cant find the BaseModel in the models/generated folder.

what should i put in the Doctrine bootstrap file to tell it they are in the models/generated folder?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in my bootstrap file resolved this issue for me:

```
Doctrine_Core::loadModels('path/to/models/generated');
```